# How to fix "deauthentication by local choice"?

Tags: wifi, dhcp, busybox, wlan, buildroot

I built an embedded Linux using [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and I have some trouble to stay connected to my AP. Cannot get an IP address more than once.

I use wpa_supplicant to connect to my AP using WPA2-PSK. It works with other AP such as my smartphone in AP mode.

When I use `iwconfig wlan0` I see that I'm associated with my AP

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ZyXEL_B3B5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 90:EF:68:D3:B3:B5   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

But I cannot get an IP address with `ifup wlan0`

```
udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
```

I should say that I'm able to get an IP address only once. If I reboot this is not possible anymore.

I managed to install `dhclient` instead of using the default DHCP client of Busybox but nothing happens (I stay blocked indefinitely)

```
dhclient wlan0
```

According to my kernel messages, it seems that I'm not continuously associated

```
[  355.459738] wlan0: authenticate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  355.461366] wlan0: authenticated
[  355.461416] wlan0: associate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  355.469353] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  355.469364] wlan0: associated
[  365.547863] wlan0: deauthenticating from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 by local choice (reason=3)
[  365.672765] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  367.169736] wlan0: authenticate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  367.171421] wlan0: authenticated
[  367.194859] wlan0: associate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  367.198561] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  367.198584] wlan0: associated
[  377.277864] wlan0: deauthenticating from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 by local choice (reason=3)
[  377.412822] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  378.899738] wlan0: authenticate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  378.901668] wlan0: authenticated
[  378.924732] wlan0: associate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  378.928437] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  378.928461] wlan0: associated
[  389.008120] wlan0: deauthenticating from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 by local choice (reason=3)
[  389.182888] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  390.689735] wlan0: authenticate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  390.691415] wlan0: authenticated
[  390.714734] wlan0: associate with 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (try 1)
[  390.720847] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  390.720870] wlan0: associated
[  400.811246] wlan0: deauthenticating from 90:ef:68:d3:b3:b5 by local choice (reason=3)
...
```

The logs of my AP

```
338     Nov 16 15:50:53 udhcpd[2404]: Received DISCOVER
339     Nov 16 15:50:53 udhcpd[2404]: unicasting packet to client yiaddr
340     Nov 16 15:50:56 udhcpd[2404]: Received DISCOVER
341     Nov 16 15:50:56 udhcpd[2404]: unicasting packet to client yiaddr
342     Nov 16 15:50:59 udhcpd[2404]: Received DISCOVER
343     Nov 16 15:50:59 udhcpd[2404]: unicasting packet to client yiaddr
```

The logs when it works (only once)

```
325     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: Received DISCOVER
326     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: unicasting packet to client yiaddr
327     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: Received REQUEST
328     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: lease = 11854360
329     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: requested = b2a8eb7f
330     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: server_id = c0a80101
331     Nov 16 15:48:37 udhcpd[2404]: unicasting packet to client yiaddr
```

How to solve it?

Comment: have you tried killing the wpa_supplicant by hand? Have you tried a different kernel? I would also define the country in the configuration file.

Comment: yes I've tried to kill wpa_supplicant but I don't have another wifi manager so it does nothing (except deassociated from the AP). I haven't a different kernel to test and it works with other AP.

Comment: Are other devices such as smartphones do connect to your AP successfully? Did you check logs/dmesg on AP itself?

Comment: Yes, both my smartphone (Android) and my notebook (Ubuntu 15.10) do connect to my AP any time (even after a reboot). logs on my AP stay empty.

Comment: I added the logs of my AP in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed the "Auto channel" option to a fixed channel and the "Channel width" option to 20 MHz in my AP and it solved my problem.

Comment: which file? I need to do the same